# How to set default image to binary field in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

In my module I have a binary field and I show that field using the image widget, but when that field has no value, it shows a blank space in the user interface. I would like to know how to set a default image to that field, so when the user has not set a value for the image field the interface would show a default image instead. I am working with odoo 12

Answer (score 0):

Keep the image in your custom module. Replace full_path with your path.

```
import base64
...

class Demo(models.Model):
...
    def _read_image(self):
        with open(full_path, 'rb') as img:
            image = base64.b64encode(img.read())
        return image

    Image = fields.Binary('Image', default=_read_image)
```

Comment: Thak you for you time but it is still showing an empty space, Could you give an example of  full_path?

Comment: with open('module_name/static/img/your image.png', 'rb') as img:
You have to store the image in this path.

Comment: @tico1993 Did it help you?

Comment: Is not working it shows an error dialog "Could not display the selected image"

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it worked for my purpose:

```
import base64

# some stuff

class YourModel(models.Model):

    # some stuff

    image = fields.Binary(compute='_set_image')

    # some stuff

    def _set_image(self):
        for record in self:
            path = record.get_image_path() #: image path in odoo folder structure, example: /odoo/images/<file>
            if not record.image:
                with open(path, 'rb') as img:
                    record.image = base64.b64encode(img.read())
```

an example of path returned by *get_image_path()*:

```
'/odoo/images/default_image.png'
```

And in view file:

```
<record ...>
    <!-- some stuff for form view -->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- some stuff -->
        <field name="image" widget="image"/>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**custom.py**

```
import base64

from odoo import api, fields, models
from odoo import tools, _
from odoo.modules.module import get_module_resource

class MyCustomModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.custom.model"

    @api.model
    def _default_image(self):
        image_path = get_module_resource('my_custom_module', 'static/src/img', 'default_image.png')
        return tools.image_resize_image_big(base64.b64encode(open(image_path, 'rb').read()))

    image = fields.Binary(
        "Photo", default=_default_image, attachment=True,
        help="This field holds the image used as photo for the employee, limited to 1024x1024px.")
```

**custom_view.xml**

```
<field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_avatar" options='{"preview_image":"image_medium"}'/>
```